# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

am learning rails using this website http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html and whenever I try starting the server using rails server, I get this error on the terminal

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

After running the command `bundle install`, I get the error:

`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

```
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/andrewmolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/bin/rake (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `open'
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `block in try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:69:in `map'
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:69:in `try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:46:in `block in execute_no_wrapper'
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/UserX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:44:in `execute_no_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'
bundler 1.9.1
erubis 2.7.0
executable-hooks 1.3.2
nokogiri 1.6.6.2
rack 1.6.0
railties 4.2.1
rake 10.1.0

extconf failed, exit code 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out

    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:72:in `run'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:157:in `install'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:7:in `with_friendly_errors'
    /Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Environment

```
Bundler   1.9.1
Rubygems  2.2.2
Ruby      2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
GEM_HOME  /Users/andrewmolo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
GEM_PATH  /Users/andrewmolo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0:/Users/andrewmolo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
RVM       1.26.10 (latest)
Git       1.8.5.2
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
```

OS = Mavericks 10.9.5

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help people with this issue but I was having the same error. What I ended up doing to fix it is commenting out the sqlite gem in my gemfile for the app. Granted I just did this a few minutes ago so I don't know if I'll run into any other issues but I use Postgres so if you use something else too, there shouldn't be an issue. Hope this helps others like me that were looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bundler has no permission to write into your file system.

> Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_3/bin/rake (Errno::EACCES)

Try running your command as sudo:

```
sudo bundle install
```

Comment: After running sudo bundle install then rails s, I get the following error.

http://pastebin.com/tQs7nthi.

What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: just realizing: your current ruby version is 2.1.2 but your rubygems are 2.2. Did you followed the environment setup from your tutorial? It requires ruby 2.2, so try to update or reinstall ruby first, like described here http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/environment/environment.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the Gemfile.lock thats not allowing you to use the latest version of of each of your gems.

To update your Gemfile.lock run the command:

```
bundle update
```

in the same directory as your Gemfile.lock file then try `bundle install` again.